# Configuring a global error handler for camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to configure an exception handler for all exceptions thrown by all routes in my camel context.  My approach is the following, with no luck:

1. Instantiate a default camel context
2. Retrieve a list of RouteDefinition from a spring context
3. Add these definitions to the camel context by calling ctx.addRouteDefinitions()
4. Add my exception handler route from a java dsl defined RotueBuilder (ctx.addRoutes(new MyErrorHandlerRouteBuilder())
5. Start the camel context

At this point, exceptions thrown inside the routes defined in spring are handled by the DefaultErrorHandler, not the one I'm trying to define.  Here's what my error handling route definition looks like

```
public class MyErrorHandlerRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    onException(Exception.class)
        .routeId("errorHandlerRoute")
        .handled(true)
        .process(new Processor() {

            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                Throwable caused = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Throwable.class);
                // do some custom processing of the exception
            }
        })
        .stop();
}
```

What else can I try, or where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Create an abstract base class and define your global error handler in the configure method. And then in your route classes extend this base class, and in their configure method call super.configure() first.

Comment: The error handling route is the only route I'm defining in code.  The other routes I want to take advantage of the error handler, will be defined in spring.  

I didn't see a way to merge the RouteDefinition (spring dsl) with the RouteBuilder (java dsl).

Comment: No this is not possible in Camel 2.x. Camel 3.0 may become more flexible in this matter.

Comment: Is there any better way to do this 2+ years later or do I need to wait for Camel 3.x?

Answer (score 7):

For future readers, this is the solution that I use for camel error handling (This is all java config but it will work as spring xml):

### 1) Setup a `DeadLetterChannelBuilder` Bean

```
@Bean
public DeadLetterChannelBuilder myErrorHandler() {
    DeadLetterChannelBuilder deadLetterChannelBuilder = new DeadLetterChannelBuilder();
    deadLetterChannelBuilder.setDeadLetterUri("direct:error");
    deadLetterChannelBuilder.setRedeliveryPolicy(new RedeliveryPolicy().disableRedelivery());
    deadLetterChannelBuilder.useOriginalMessage();
    return deadLetterChannelBuilder;
}
```

Now this bean will be responsible for picking up errors and directing them to the `direct:error` URI.

### 2) Setup your error handling route

You will want a route to listen on the URI `direct:error` because this is where your errors are now being routed.

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:error")
            .to("log:error")
            .end();
}
```

As you can see now that all your errors are being routed to the above route you have the flexibility to implement complex error handling logic globally.

### 3) Inject your global error handler into your routes

You still need to inject your error handling bean into each route. I wish camel would handle this automatically but I have not found a way. Although with this approach the code duplication/overhead is minimal.

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    errorHandler(myErrorHandler)
    from("myStartingUri")
            .to("myEndDestination")
            .end();
}
```

Looking at the documentation for springs xml based config I think you would need to put `<route errorHandlerRef="myErrorHandler">` in your route definition.

Comment: How did you inject the global error handler into routes. How did you get the instance of myErrorHandler. (New to Camel). TIA

Answer (score 1):

Error handlers are route builder specific in Java DSL. You need to create one per route builder. Or in your case, you need to define it in Spring DSL (as you seems to define your routes in Spring).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  My goal was to remove the necessity of defining this error handler along with your routes.  Basically, I'd like have this error handler functionality available for all routes even when it's not explicitly stated in the route definition.

Looks like I'll need to give this up.

Answer (score 0):

After retrieving your XML routes as a Resource from an application context and loading them to the camel context you will have a RoutesDefinition object you can try to manipulate like

```
Resource xmlRoutes = applicationContext.getResource("path/to/xml/routes");
RoutesDefinition routeDefinitions = camelContext.loadRoutesDefinition(xmlRoute.getInputStream());
for (RouteDefinition routeDefinition : routeDefinitions.getRoutes()) {
    routeDefinition
        .onException(Exception.class)
        .handled(true)
        // do some custom processing of the exception
```